# Convolution in Hardy spaces

Tags: harmonic-analysis, power-series, convolution

**Question** Are there non-trivial restrictions on the coefficients of functions in Hardy spaces ($H_p(\mathbb{D})$, $p<1$) that make a subspace that is closed under convolution?

**Definition** The Hardy space $H_p$ is the set of power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ which have finite norm 
\begin{equation*}
\| f\|_{H_p}= \lim_{\rho\rightarrow 1^{-}}\| g\|_{L_p},  
\end{equation*}
where $g(\theta) = f(\rho e^{i\theta})$.

**Definition** The convolution of two functions $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
f*g(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n z^n
\end{equation}

**Question** If $f,g\in H_p$ and $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}\in \ell_{\infty}$, then $\{a_nb_n\}\in \ell_{\infty}$. Is $f*g\in H_p$?